# My character's SpriteNode is shaking when moving, why?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, shake

My main character, which is a SKSpriteNode with physicsBody, is shaking when moving or jumping.

I am moving my character by changing is `character.physicsBody.velocity.dx`'s (in order to simulate acceleration or deceleration), and I use `applyImpulse` to make him jump.

**Code :**

To move :

```
 [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx - 30, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
```

To jump :

```
if (!isJumping)
{
    [self.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 6.0f)];
}
```

In addition, I use a method i found on internet to change the camera position on the map, so as to follow the character :

```
- (void)setViewpointCenter:(CGPoint)position
{
    NSInteger x = MAX(position.x, self.size.width / 2);
    NSInteger y = MAX(position.y, self.size.height / 2);
    x = MIN(x, (self.map.mapSize.width * self.map.tileSize.width) - self.size.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (self.map.mapSize.height * self.map.tileSize.height) - self.size.height / 2);

    CGPoint actualPosition = CGPointMake(x, y);
    CGPoint centerOfView = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
     CGPoint viewPoint = CGPointSubtract(centerOfView, actualPosition);
self.map.position = viewPoint;
}
```

**Result ?**

[Here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMuvszUg8bo) (recorded with QuickTime from iPhone 5).  You can easily see the trouble on this video and how much this is breaking my head (and my game that I've just started to develop).

Indeed, there is often (not each time, sometimes it is perfect) like a ghost and he becomes blurred. I don't understand nothing, i do not find any solution.

I tried this on simulator and on my device, same effect.

I can post more code if you want, and can tell you everything, and I hope someone will find where I did something wrong !

*Thanx in advance !*

Paul

**Edit 1 :**

Thank you for comments !

I have 8 draws shown on the screen, 145 nodes and no real problem is appearing with physics !

To move my character to the left, i just run :

-(void)moveToLeft
{

```
    if (isJumping && isOnRightSide)
    {
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(-self.physicsBody.velocity.dx / 2.0, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    }
    [self setIsOnRightSide:NO];
    [self setIsStopping:NO];
    [self setIsRunning:YES];
    [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx - 30, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
}
```

And to the right :

```
-(void)moveToRight
{
    if (isJumping && !isOnRightSide)
    {
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx / 2.0, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    }
    [self setIsStopping:NO];
    [self setIsOnRightSide:YES];
    [self setIsRunning:YES];
    [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx + 30, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
}
```

And then :

```
if (_isStopping)
{
    if (isOnRightSide)
    {
        int ralentissement = MIN(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 10);
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx - ralentissement, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    }
    else
    {
        int ralentissement = MAX(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx, -10);
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx - ralentissement, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    }


    if (abs(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx) < 1)
    {
        isRunning = NO;
        _isStopping = NO;
        if (self.hasActions)
            [self removeAllActions];
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    }
}


if (isOnRightSide && isRunning && self.physicsBody.velocity.dx < 150 && !_isStopping)
{
    [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx + 10, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
}
else if (!isOnRightSide && isRunning && self.physicsBody.velocity.dx > -150 && !_isStopping)
{
    [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx - 10, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
}

if (abs(self.physicsBody.velocity.dx) > 150)
{
    if (isOnRightSide)
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(150, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
    else
        [self.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(-150, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy)];
}
```

Is there a better solution to apply force constantly with acceleration and deceleration ?

I checked all my images, they all have same sizes!

I turned off the camera function and indeed, **shakes stopped!** So this function must be the wrong part, I have found it on raywenderlich, and I have no idea of how I could replace it. Do you know how ? Thanks!

**Edit 2 :**

So, I tried to move the call of my camera movement method to didFinishUpdate, and **it works really better** ! This shaking feeling disappeared and I can now play without that bad experience.

*BUT* there is still one thing happening when the character jump (which is done thanks to `applyForce` method) : when he is going up, he still seems to go down sometimes, just 1 pixel here or there. It's very special and I don't know if a real issue of Sprite Kit or if it's my texture which are too big or anything else. I tried to look at the animation with physics body drawn and in fact there are some vertical shaking (more exactly, the rectangle colored in blue seems to be blinking).

Have you some ideas about that last issue ?

The horizontal movement are now perfect, thanks you all for your help.

Comment: When I watched your video, the first thing that came on my mind is that something is wrong with  your animation. Check your character animation images size. Probably this is not the problem, but you can check it. Also you can show how you move your character left and right in the code.

Comment: Also you can enable showsPhysics in your view controller as well as showsNode and showsDrawCount. It's useful when debugging.

Comment: Cool art! I think I may know what the issue might be.  Can you turn off that camera function and try jumping around? Does it still stutter?

Comment: Try centering your camera view in the didSimulatePhysics method.

Comment: Thanks you for answers ! I have just edited main post for more information about what you said !

Comment: In what method are you centering your camera view?

Comment: I call this method every frame in update method. This is how I can have this camera following the character, but i'm not sure that is the best way to do a camera following the character. Do you know how I could ?

Comment: are you setting velocity or doing other movement type stuff inside of any kind of update or looping method?

Comment: Yes I am changing velocity in update method as I mentionned in Edit 1 (last code block above). I adjust velocity according to his state (running, stopping ...) Is that bad to do it here ?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out @Polo? I seem to experience the same problem whether I am following my character with the camera or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had this same problem (also following ray's tutorials) ..  You're making the camera animate by following your character which looks really cool, but it causes the stuttering. the world is moving one way, and the character is moving the opposite direction, you get a treadmill kinda thing going and that causes the character to stutter.  in ray's current book he does:

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
   let target = getCenterPointWithTarget(player.position)
   worldNode.position += (target - worldNode.position) * 0.1
```

I'm sure this is pretty similar to what you're doing right??  this is making it so the worldNode is constantly trying to catch up to the players movements.  It gives the camera that elastic feeling.

try just going

```
worldNode.position = getCenterPointWithTarget(player.position)
```

If this fixed it, then we've narrowed it down further.  The problem here is you lost that cool camera easing effect.

The thing is that I don't know where you are making your changes to the players movements.. I don't know if these are just one time methods that you call, or they run in your update loop.

I'll just give you an example of how I'm doing it in my game:

**in Update:**

```
    // update ship position
    ship.update(self.delta)
```

i move the screen in didFinishUpdate so I make sure this is the last thing that happens.  Hopefully this stops any stuttering.

**didFinishUpdate**

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    // move BG Nodes
    self.moveBGNodes()
}
```

**moveBGNodes method**

```
func moveBGNodes(){

    // method that calculates camera position (stops camera at screen edges)
    let target = self.pointToCenterViewOn(ship.position)

    // ease gameworld into ship's position
    gameLayer.position += (target - gameLayer.position) * 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot for this answer ! I am not doing as you said first, but i am already doing the second method you told me, so : `self.map.position = viewPoint;` (others lines are just used to make the camera stay in the map).  I tried to call my camera method in didFinishUpdate and it's really better (i was doing it in update method). So as to move my character, i have some boolean values which i test every frame in update method, and do what i write above on case by case. Have you got a better solution ? Thanks you a lot !

Comment: It's on a case by case basis.  If it's working for you right now just stick with that.  If you can think of a cleaner solution, or your current solution is making things difficult, then you should come up with a different way of doing it.  Glad I could help.

Comment: I thought about a new way to do this but I have no ideas. There is always few booleans values that I check in update method in order to apply forces and adjust texture and animations of the character. It works well like this but if you have ideas I would be happy to try  to improve this.